# Raspbian: Is the filesystem table name /etc/fstab hard-coded or is it a default that can be overridden somewhere?

Tags: raspbian

I'm aware that the Raspbian mount command can specify a different filesystem table with the -T and --fstab arguments. But can you change the name of the table that is used at boot time? i.e. is this parameterised somewhere?

Comment: Do you want to provide multiple, alternative fstabs?

Comment: Probably not. Just curious to see if the name is hard-coded or a parameter default somewhere. Thanks

Comment: Really they should have migrated this to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) since it is not Raspbian's `mount`, it is GNU/Linux's, and more generally unix's (or POSIX's).  The man page has a redhat contact address on it, is from the `util-linux` package, and notes "A mount command existed in Version 5 AT&T UNIX" (more than 3 decades ago).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Maybe*, since in fact the way this works is `mount` called by an init service.  On current versions of Raspbian, init is systemd, and looking at `man systemd-mount` (which pertains to services with a `.mount` suffix) implies that it might indeed be hardcoded.  However, if you really wanted to, you probably could find a way to disable that and create your own service that plays an appropriate role.  Since there are much simpler ways to accomplish the same thing (e.g., symlink `/etc/fstab`) I doubt anyone has done so.

Earlier versions of Raspbian using SysV init presumably used a script which you could edit.  The problem with this is your changes would not likely be protected from system updates.  A better approach would be, as with systemd, to tweak init's service set and supplant your own.

In both cases, doing so would require a bit of diligence and study since getting the root filesystem mounted is usually a critical element of the boot process and must be properly completed before most other things can happen.